# Проверка скорости сети

Tags: bash, crontab

При загрузки системы crontab запускает скрипт скачивающий файлы с других серверов и иногда скорость скачивания небольшая(полмегабайта). Для восстановления нормальной скорости скачивания иногда приходиться перезагружать сервер.
Есть ли возможность автоматизировать перезагрузку crontab или систему если скорость скачивания, например, полмегабайта в течении 10-15 минут?

Comment: Добавить условие в скрипт который выполняет кронтаб

Comment: Каким образом в скрипте сделать прерывание скачивания, если в данный момент этот же скрипт выполняет скачивание с малой скоростью?

Comment: обратитесь к разработчику скрипта.

Comment: Логика скрипта следующая - есть файл, качаем, нет файла не качаем, при скачивании используется например wget.

Comment: если на perl - сделать форк, если на sh - просто вызов ещё одного скрипта, который к примеру будет спать 10 минут - и проверять, завершился ли wget. Если нет, отправлять систему в ребут. почему скорость проверяется скачиванием файла, а не проверкой состояния порта? включить, выключить сеть не достаточно? нужен именно ребут?

Comment: У вас проблемы не в скрипте. Вам надо найти причину почему скорость падает. Перезагрузка сервера — это вообще внештатная ситуация. Либо у вас «сервер» — это не сервер.